# DotNet - MVC: Testing for validating css minification

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, azure-pipelines, bundletransformer

I need to test that all CSS/SCSS files in a project have been successfully minified in the build process of a .Net MVC App, or at least test that they are valid CSS.

Currently, the project is built in VSO/VSTS, and syntax errors in the CSS will not fail the build, and the app is deployed with broken CSS.

I know very little about .Net apps, I know that the main project is ProjectName.Web, the tests are ProjectName.Web.Test, and if I want to test something, I create a corresponding "-Test" class in the ".Test" project, but where would I put a test for minification of files? The files are bundled in ProjectName.Web/App_Data/BundleConfig, and use BundleTransformer to minify the files, how do I check it worked correctly after build?

Any pointers are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://unminify.com/) is a link to de-minify css. I would recommend you de-minify it, identify the problems, then minify it again. Usually they are small things. If you can post the deminified code then I would be happy to help.